# MQL4 offset returning different time

Tags: mql4

I have folowing code in MQL4:

```
#property copyright "Copyright 2023, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

MqlRates bar_main_pair[];
MqlRates bar_H1[];
    
string main_pair = "EURUSD";
int HistoryLength = 1000;
    
int OnInit()
{
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnTick()
{
    ArraySetAsSeries(bar_H1, true);
    CopyRates(_Symbol, PERIOD_H1, 0, HistoryLength + 100, bar_H1);
       
    ArraySetAsSeries(bar_main_pair, true);
    CopyRates(main_pair, PERIOD_H1, 0, HistoryLength + 100, bar_main_pair);
          
    Print(bar_H1[82].time, " ", bar_main_pair[82].time);
}
```

but on FTMO it is returning different times for EURUSD and GBPUSD. _Symbol is GBPUSD. Can someone please advise why?

[image]

I actually extended the Print in the code:
[image]

and result is strange ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running this through the strategy tested. When in tester mode, if you are refencing a different chart the the current bar (Bar[0]) is not available to read, this will therefore be producing a 1 hour difference in your code. Changing your start bar to 1 should solve the problem.

Comment: I extended the code ...

Comment: Why have you not tried what I suggested? Change the start bars to start at 1, eg., `CopyRates(_Symbol, PERIOD_H1, 1, HistoryLength + 100, bar_H1);`

Comment: Actually I did but is the same result. As 0 bar and bar 1 is the same time ... the bar 62 is different time .. not sure is some candle is missing in FTMO ... do you have any idea?